# Copyright on a physical object where no patent exists

Tags: copyright, patents

Lets say my company make a new shape of Rubik's Cube (a round ball twisty puzzle) and we call it a "Ball Cube" (my company is called "Puzzles" so its a "Puzzles Ball Cube").

I patent the "Ball Cube" and start selling it...

20 years later the patent expires and lots of other twisty puzzle manufacturers create the "Ball Cube" and call it their own brand so lets just say "Rubik's Ball Cube" and "LanLan Ball Cube" and "China Ball Cube".

Are they free to do so? do i legally own copyright for the "Ball Cube" phrase or the design of the original? Or would I have to file for a trademark?

Can a physical object like this twitsy ball cube be protected under copyright after the aptent expires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to establish [trademark protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark) on the phrase "Ball Cube": copyright is not generally a good way to protect names or other short phrases.  See, for example, [Can I copyright the name of my band?](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-protect.html#band) from the U. S. Copyright Office, which notes that "names are not protected by copyright law."

Furthermore, you're interested in preventing others from selling a similar object using a similar name, and that's precisely what trademark protection is for.

The ball cube design would potentially be eligible for copyright protection, but you should be aware that this protection would not extend to elements of its design that originated in Rubik's Cube, because your design would be a [derivative work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work).

Comment: So only the design would be copyright-able? Im guessing the PHYSICAL objet cannot be protected under copyright.

After talking to somebody that apparantly "knows law" as soon as the ball cube is invented it is protected by copyright and nobody can then copy it. I do not believe this to be true?

Comment: @LukeTerzich copyright is infringed when someone makes a copy.  Whether you wish to describe that as protection of the object itself or of its design seems unimportant.  If someone copies, for example, a mass-produced sculpture, is it important to know which specific exemplar of that sculpture was the source of the copy?

Comment: Could i then take the company to court that is reproducing my "Ball Cube"? (even thought i have no trademark or anything).

Comment: @LukeTerzich you can take anyone to court for anything in many jurisdictions; whether you'll succeed is another matter.  Whether a given object infringes the copyright depends on subjective judgments that would have to be decided by the court.  You might also want to consider whether Erno Rubik might sue you for infringing his copyright when you created your derivative work.  You might also be interested to know that [in 2016, the EUCJ ruled that the shape of Rubik's Cube was not sufficient to grant it trademark protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube#Trademarks)

Comment: Can you copyright a product's design? I thought that's what patents were for.

Comment: @cHao if the product is, for example, an art object, then its design would be protected by copyright.  If it's a machine, then its design would be potentially subject to patent protection, though elements might also be subject to copyright protection.  There's doubtless a good deal of gray area in between.

Comment: Copyright law is actually pretty strict about what it covers -- see 17 USC §102. The extent to which this "Ball Cube" could be considered a *sculptural work*, that's the extent to which copyright law could apply. (No other category even comes close.) Pretty sure it *doesn't* apply, though, and wouldn't be the right tool even if it did. (It doesn't prohibit independent creation.) You need a design patent, at least in the US.

Comment: @cHao The gray area I meant to invoke is embodied in your phrase "pretty sure."  It is a subjective judgment.

Comment: You could also apply for a type of patent called a design patent. Unlike the better known utility patent, it is all about the looks of a product.  It is also possible that to make it work some actual functional improvement to the workings might be made that is patentable under a utility patent.